# Spring Boot WebFlux NettyServerCustomizer does not work

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-web

I have very simple application, I read I can use NettyServerCustomizer to customize NettyServer. But it does not work, implementation of the NettyServerCustomizer interface is not being called.
Project is generated by Spring Initializr

Code of application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @GetMapping
    public Mono<String> test() {
        return Mono.just("test");
    }

    @Bean
    public NettyServerCustomizer nettyCustomizer() {
        return builder -> builder.port(9909);
    }

}
```

pom

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 2):

Defining a bean of type NettyServerCustomizer doesn't have any effect by itself, you can get the desired result with `WebServerFactoryCustomizer`

```
@Bean
public WebServerFactoryCustomizer getWebServerFactoryCustomizer() {
    WebServerFactoryCustomizer<ConfigurableReactiveWebServerFactory> customizer = factory -> factory.setPort(9909);
    return customizer;
}
```

Also note that the port is also read from the `Environment` using the property `server.port`, which I think the cleanest way besides it has a great deal of flexibility regarding the source of the property value.

If you are wondering why NettyServerCustomizer doesn't work, a bit of digging in the code reveals that this class is not injected into `NettyReactiveWebServerFactory` in any way.

Comment: This is fixed in Spring Boot 2.2: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/78ea42314834ea17b8e53c2bc928d516a9a2db21/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/reactive/ReactiveWebServerFactoryConfiguration.java#L73

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66097881/spring-webflux-grafana-nettyservercustomizer-this-query-results-in-more-tha